# Object is set to Null Reference when editing gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my web application, I have a grid-view and this grid-view is databounded. Above this grid-view, I have a text box where user can first enter the Employee ID and show the Employee Name in the grid view. In the grid view, it has the edit icon. When the user hit that edit icon, some text boxes in the grid view will appear and the use can edit the text in the text box. I got it working so far. However, my problem is when I am trying to edit the empty text box in the grid view, it gave me this error:

> Object is not set to an instance of an object

All I did is to check if the text box is null. This does ignore the error but not really what I want

```
protected void txtEditedEmployeeID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseManager dbManager = Common.GetDbManager();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewAddEmployee.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtEmployee= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeID");
        if (txtEmployee!= null)
        {
            string personID = txtEmployee.Text;
            DataSet dsRE = dbManager.GetEmployeeNameByID(personID);
            for (int i = 0; i < dsRE.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string employeeFirstName = dsRE.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
                string employeeLastName = dsRE.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeName")).Text = staffLastName + " " + staffFirstName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

HTML ASP.NET Code

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeID">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged= "txtEditedEmployeeID_TextChanged" Text='<%#Bind("Employee_ID") %>'Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
              </EditItemTemplate>

              <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeID" runat="server"  CssClass="GridInput" Text='<%#Bind("Employee_ID") %>'Width="90px"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
      <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployee" runat="server" ReadOnly ="true" Text='<%#Bind("Full_Name") %>'Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeName" runat="server" CssClass="GridInput" Text='<%#Bind("Full_Name") %>'Width="90px"></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Which line is causing the Error?

Comment: @MatthewSpencer, 'string personID = txtEmployee.Text;' is causing the problem if I didn't put the if(txtEmployee != null) in my code

Comment: `txtEditedEmployeeID` for which you fire the event is inside GridView or above the GridView ? It will be better if you post aspx markup also.

Comment: because the texbox isnt in the row and its in the header?  FindControl on the grid instead?

Comment: @DragonBorn - Why you are calling `txtEditedEmployeeID_TextChanged` when user change some text in the textbox, this event will be triggered. What you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: What I am trying to do is when user enter sometext in one textbox, the other textbox will show the result of what user entered. So let say I entered employeeID 1234, employeeName Peter will displayed in the txtEmployeeName inside the grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As on Edit `txtEmployeeID` will appear for that row only Not for all the rows of `GridView` and on TextBox Change event you are finding all row edited TextBox which is not appear till now so you may try this:

```
  protected void txtEditedEmployeeID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DatabaseManager dbManager = Common.GetDbManager();
      TextBox txt = sender as TextBox; // Edited TextBox
      GridViewRow row = (txt.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);// Row of Edited TextBox
      TextBox txtEmployee= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeID");
      string personID = txtEmployee.Text;
      DataSet dsRE = dbManager.GetEmployeeNameByID(personID);
      for (int i = 0; i < dsRE.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          string employeeFirstName = dsRE.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
          string employeeLastName = dsRE.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
          ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeName")).Text = staffLastName + " " + staffFirstName;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of

```
TextBox txtEmployee= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeID");
if (txtEmployee!= null)
{
    string personID = txtEmployee.Text;
```

You should write it like this

```
TextBox txtEmployee = new TextBox();
txtEmployee = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmployeeID"); 
if (!string.isNullorEmpty(txtEmployee.Text))
{
    string personID = txtEmployee.Text;
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, you mean txtEmployee.Text right? However, If I tried that, it still have the same problem